# Синоніми слова "сир" у побутовому спілкуванні

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

Як відомо, коли йдеться про *сир*, то це слово може означати як кисломолочний продукт, так і продукт сироваріння. Однак ці обидва продукти користуються великим попитом серед населення, і часто виникає непорозуміння, який саме з продуктів має на увазі співрозмовник.

Чи існують синоніми (або, можливо, словосполучення), які дозволяють однозначно відрізняти ці продукти?

В моїй родині, коли мова йде про кисломолочний продукт, то ми кажемо *домашній сир*, а коли про продукт сироваріння - *твердий сир*. Але це є неточні терміни і за певних обставин можуть припускати подвійне тлумачення.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При пошуку однозначного уточнювального означення для слова *сир* підводні камені на кожному кроці.

Прикметник *домашній* стосується місця-способу виготовлення, і *домашнім* (на противагу *магазинному*, *заводському*) може бути будь-який сир. 
<sub>(Вікіпедія, знаючи це, все одно [наводить](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80) «домашній» назвою сиру кисломолочного, але вона змінна).</sub>

Називати кисломолочний сир *м'яким* (на противагу *твердому*) не вийде, бо до категорії м'яких сирів належать [вершковий сир](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80) і [ще й ті](https://olympica.com.ua/438539-yakijj-vin-m-yakijj-sir.html), які мають термін визрівання кілька тижнів: моцарелла, банон, брі тощо. Також за вмістом вологи сири можуть бути напівм'які (як мюнстер) і напівтверді (як емменталь).

Так само *білий* чи *жовтий* сир — лише характеристика кольору. Білим може бути і кисломолочний і м'який сир, *жовтим* — твердий. [Мімолет](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82) взагалі помаранчевий до червоного.

Фета (білий, м'який) чи сулугуні (жовтий, твердий) — це *розсільні* сири, за способом виготовлення.

Я так розумію, що якщо людина знайома з [різновидами сирів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2), то так їх і називає, і тоді слово «*сир*» позначає традиційний для нас кисломолочний або просто найчастіше вживаний у її харчуванні, а якщо незнайома, то тоді всі. **Чи існує спосіб однозначного вказання на вид сиру? Називати «творог» *кисломолочним* сиром** (або ж, чесно, краще просто **сиром**), **а всі інші види — за їхніми видовими назвами.**

Comment: Чесно кажучи, мені не дуже очевидно, як цей допис відповідає на запитання «Чи існують синоніми (або, можливо, словосполучення), які дозволяють однозначно відрізняти ці продукти?» Це більше схоже на підтвердження тези «так, є складність у доборі правильного слова».  Якщо можна, позначне найголовніше шрифтом абощо.

Comment: як щодо *сільський сир*? Чи може *селянський*.

Comment: @yola, та ж проблема, що й з _домашнім_

Comment: Дуже логічно, але як Ви аргументуєте за «кисломолочний»? Хіба деякі інші види сиру не роблять з кислого молока (окрім «тварога»/«творога»)? Якщо просто «за традицією» — так і «домашній сир» можна вважати традиційною назвою такого сиру.

Comment: До речі, в Вікіпедіях рос. «[кисломолочный сыр](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кисломолочный_сыр)» = англ. «[sour milk cheese](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sour_milk_cheese)» посилаються на дещо інше, ніж укр. «[тваріг](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Домашній_сир)» = рос. «[творог](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Творог)» = англ. «[quark](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_(dairy_product))» (хоч, може це і помилка, я на цьому не знаюся).

Comment: @sasha, гарне зауваження, напевно, в цьому я помиляюсь.

Answer (score 16):

Слова *творог* в українській мові немає. Російське *творог* (домашній сир) українською мовою просто *сир*. А російське *сыр* – *твердий сир*.

В більшості випадків подовжують вживати слово *творо́г* для домашнього сиру, незважаючи на те, що такого слова в українській мові немає.

Comment: Якщо не зрозуміло з контексту, то часто додають "кисломолочний, кислий, білий" або ж навпаки "твердий"

Comment: Я б сказав, творог не «продовжують вживати», а «почали вживати». У 80-х/90-х ніякого «творога» в відомій мені розмовній українській мові ще не було (при тому, що загалом мова була доволі засмічена русизмами).

Answer (score 5):

я вживаю `творог`, іноді `творіг` - все як водиться: з фрікативним г. можете вважати це або [росіянізмом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3), або [полонізмом](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twar%C3%B3g) на власний розсуд

UPD:
ба більше, у німців є ще коротша, раптово спільнокоріннева з творогом форма - [quark](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Quark#Etymology_1), але є ризики переплутати з більш розповсюдженим синтетичним [значенням](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quark#Etymology_1). Проте можна буде жартувати, що чим більше відомо, що це сир, то менше відомо про те, що це творіг

Comment: Хай це суржик, та важко призвичаїтися до «норми» називати однаковим словом те, що розрізняється не тільки у мовах оточення (польська, білоруська, російська, турецька), а й у тій самій англійській. Власне я не бачу нічого поганого у поступовій легалізації творога.

Comment: В той же час "сирники" — це "сирники", а не "творожники"

Comment: Цитуємо вікі: "тверді сири з'явилися порівняно недавно (XIX ст.)" - хоча не зрозуміло, це про з'явилися в Україні, чи у світі? Тобто, потреби розрізняти сири не було, тому й різних слів не придумали.

Comment: @Sassa NF Сир зі зрозумілих причин з'явився раніше за «твердий сир», бо виготовляти його простіше. Судячи з етимології, «творог» також має давнє походження і, начебто, перегукується кореневим поняттям з романськими мовами. Цікаво, що у відеокурсі 90-х поляки кажуть «ser biały» і «ser żółty» (так само подекуди в українській), а не «twaróg».

Comment: Так, до відома, - за своїм видом та смаком німецький quark мало схожий на український/польський/російський сир/twaróg/творог.

Comment: Якщо немає відповідного слова в українській, то його треба запозичити. Так робили завжди, всю історію, у всіх мовах. Мені, в принципі, все одно, яке слово вживати, але було б логічно запозичувати з найближчих до української мов. І якщо так, то це, звичайно, буде "творог" або "творіг". Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Навіть запозичення слова «творог» не вирішує проблеми двозначності слова «сир». Для «кисломолочного сиру» назва є, для «некисломолочного» — нема. В російській «сир» у значенні «кисломолочний сир» занепало, тому проблема неоднозначності вирішилась, але українська мова ще надто далека до цього.

Comment: @PYPY в польскій, наприклад, розрізняють тваруґ і серек вейський, тобто сільський, домашній сир %) 

але і власне [тваруґ](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twar%C3%B3g) є терміном неоднозначним і в деяких місцинах може позначати суміш сабжа зі сметаною і смаковими додатками. на жаль вікіпедія не позначає чи то мішають його з битою сметаною, тобто вершками, або ж зі звиклою сметаною, тобто сметаною

але тим не менш, використовувати слово `творіг` для позначення свіжого сиру, нмд, настільки ж допустимо, як і вживання слова `ксерокс` для позначення копіювальних пристроїв

Comment: Ви не зрозуміли: як би ми додатково не назвали кисломолочний сир (кисломолочним, домашнім, творогом і т.д.), «сир» усе одно зберігає обидва значення. Насправді в нас нема назви не для того, що росіяни називають «творог», а для того, що росіяни называють «сыр».

Comment: @PYPY я розумію, що, скажімо, так само не можна буде відрізнити моцірелу від чеддера вживаючи просто слово сир, навіть якщо вживати слово творіг для позначення всім відомого продукту, або ж навіть не вживати. Питання ж було про розмовне розділення сиру-який-творіг і сиру-який-не-творіг

Comment: І моцарела, і чедер належать до продуктів із сирзаводів. Кисломолочний сир належить до продуктів з молокозаводів. Укр. «сир» охоплює і те, й інше. Рос. «сыр» — лише продукти сирзаводів. Перекладіть слово «сыр» на українську так, щоб воно точно не означало «творог», але охоплювало моцарелу, чедер, бринзу й голландський сир.

Comment: @PYPY наразі мені ніяк не вдається без уточнення що це моцарелла, чедер, бринза, голандський сир або іниший нетворіг

Comment: Гадаꙇу, бажано вживати саме _творіг_, а не _творог_, бо маꙇемо за норму _пиріг_, а не _пирог_.

Answer (score 4):

У словнику Фасмера:

> WORD: тваро́г
>       GENERAL: обычно тво́ро́г, укр. тварíг, блр. тво́рог, болг. тваро́г, чеш., слвц. tvaroh, польск. twaróg, в.-луж. twaroh, н.-луж. twarog.

(Виключив решту статті з гіпотезами походження)

Тобто: по-перше, слово є, хоча б в діалектах. По-друге: воно спільнословʼянське. По-третє: в першому складі "а", а не "о"!
Чому російська і білоруська мають там "о", питання окреме, але не принципове тут.

Отже, я б не переймався тим, що хтось виключив зі словників. Є причина використання і є слово, значить, треба вживати.

Comment: творог як на мене некрасиве так явний русизм

Comment: «Чому російська і білоруська мають там „о“, питання окреме» — з тієї ж причини, через яку в нас «творити». З виключеної решти статті виходить, що українські сучасне «творити» і старе «тваріг» (а також російські сучасні «творить», «тварь») — однокореневі. Можливо, початково в корені був саме «а», хтозна, але зараз і в російській, і в українській, і в білоруській у багатьох словах там часто «о» (тому не факт, то «тваріг» в сучасній мові має бути саме через «а»).

Comment: В українській може бути полонізмом (що поснює, чому «тваріг», а не «творіг», і відсутність у центрально-східних діалектах).

Comment: @Sasha Нагадаꙇу, шчо маꙇемо слово з таким ж самим корнем _твар-ина_.

Comment: @stegetsj, але ж _творити_, _твір_, _творіння_ теж однокореневі.

Comment: Так, але _а_ з _о_ чергуꙇе сꙇа [частенꙇко](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par1), до того ж, _тв**о**р-інꙇе_ походе від _тв**о**р-ити_, же так само _г**о**р-іти_ і _г**о**р-інꙇе_, але _г**а**рꙇачка_. До речи, не знаꙇу чому Фасмер вказав блр. через _о_, хоча всꙇуди через _а_ ([тарас.](https://be-tarask.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тварог) і [зв.](https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тварог)). До того ж, моск. _творог_ теж звучитꙇ ꙇак _твароґ_.

Answer (score 1):

У разі потреби наш народ сам мимоволі знайде потрібне слово. З іншого боку, в тій же англійські мові нашу сметану називають двома словами [sour cream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sour_cream) (прикметник та іменник) і не морочать собі цим голову. Тому нам також не варто цим перейматися. Додам лишень, що твердий сир називають часто голландським сиром. Це по суті синоніми.

Comment: Якщо ви підете в магазин, то побачите що "голландський сир" - одна із назв твердих сирів. "Ти купив голландський сир? Ні, я купив сметанковий!".

Comment: У польскій сметана - то сметана, сміетанка - то вершки і тут варто перепровірити жирність, і є ще грік йогурт окремо. Й це притому, що на близькому сході доси триває війна і вони не шчиплять свій аналог.

Comment: Саме нашу сметану в англійській мові називають _smetana_ (surprise, surprise): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smetana_(dairy_product). Як один з видів sour cream.

Comment: @Artemix [словник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=голендер&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) · [Ніковського](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ніковський_Андрій_Васильович): Голендер — _гал._ сыр голландский. Щодо сира, зустрічається [також:](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=творог&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) _рум._ ґляґанець. Але, схоже, це [бринза](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Бринза), бо ґляґ це [сичуг](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сичуг).